# Entity Framework Delete related entities

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have two datagrids. First shows forums, second - related users. I manage to add and delete forums from first datagrid because MyForums is an ObservableCollection and I can attach CollectionChanged event to it.

The second datagrid, as you can see from xaml, is a subset of first one. When I add users to it, they are saved to the DB. However, I struggled to find a way to delete a user. All I came up with is this solution from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/data/jj574514.aspx :

```
foreach (var users in _context.User.Local.ToList())
{
   if (users.Forum == null)
   {
      _context.User.Remove(users);
   }
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works, but to my mind it's not very elegant, since every time I press save button, it itterates through all the users. There should be a smarter way of doing this. I would appreciate your help.

My simplified model looks like this:

[image: Entity Framework model]

Databinging in xaml is done this way:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding MyForums}" x:Key="CVSForums" x:Name="CVSForums" />
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding User, Source={StaticResource CVSForums}}" x:Key="CVSUsers" x:Name="CVSUsers" />
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVSForums}}" x:Name="ForumList" />
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVSUsers}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserUsername, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="UserName" x:Name="UserCol2" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserPassword, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="UserPassword" x:Name="UserCol3" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Relevant part of code looks like this:

```
MyForums = new ObservableCollection<DB.Forum>(_context.Forum.Local);
MyForums.CollectionChanged += MyForums_CollectionChanged;

void MyForums_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:

                foreach (DB.Forum single_forum in e.NewItems.OfType<DB.Forum>())
                {
                    _context.Forum.Add(single_forum);
                    var single_forumoptions = new DB.ForumOptions() { Forum = single_forum };
                    _context.ForumOptions.Add(single_forumoptions);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:

                foreach (DB.Forum single_forum in e.OldItems.OfType<DB.Forum>())
                {
                    _context.Forum.Remove(single_forum);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're going for here. You seem to have deleting a single entity working fine. You can delete the user object in the same way? It's also unclear what you mean by Users being a subset of Forums. That isn't true by the way you're relationship is defined.

Comment: I understand that if you delete a forum instance, you want the related users be deleted too?

Comment: Why not just remove the users when you remove the forum?  Your model shows that a user is related to a single forum.  So, in your Remove case, as you're iterating through the forums, before you remove the forum, why not just remove the users of that forum and then remove the forum?

Comment: @Shoe: I would delete it the same way but I can't figure out how to fire CollectionChanged event for Users.

Comment: @noobob and M.Ob: Forum deletion along with its users is fine. What I want to achieve is this: let's say forum has five users and I need to delete only two of them.

Comment: You don't need collection changed event. When button is clicked, delete from db and delete from your list.

Comment: @Shoe, can you provide me a glue of how to determine the deleted rows in a grid, .i.e. the deleted users. Something similar to what I have: e.OldItems.OfType<DB.Forum>()